# Use drag and drop cursor java swing or javafx

Tags: java, swing, javafx, mouse-cursor

I would like to change the cursor to use the drag and drop "move" and "move and copy" cursors in my application on a panel when I perform certain actions. The area is using swing inside of a swing node so a swing (Apply to panel) or JavaFx (Applying to swing node) solution would work.

I did find swing cursors DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop and DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop but when I apply them my cursor doesn't change. (And I know I am applying the cursor correctly as applying other cursors work fine)

EDIT: Note that when not nested in a SwingNode and in a JFrame instead the cursor does change to what I want. I have amended the code example to emulate the environment I am in where it doesn't work:

```
public class Temp extends Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR)); //Change this
            swingNode.setContent(panel);
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(swingNode));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: A good question will [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "improve your chances of getting an answer".

Comment: @kleopatra - I have updated the question now.

Comment: Unless that is an answer below (which it does not seem to be), it should be an [edit] to the question. BTW - what is the purpose of mixing Swing and Java-FX?

Comment: That is the environment I am writing the code in and is out of my control - I will do your suggestion and update the question.

Comment: Your example app doesn’t implement [drag and drop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag_drop_feature.htm).

Comment: @jewelsea It's not supposed to - I am wanting to use the icon from it without using the drag and drop system for a custom in app drag. The motivation is I got an operation where you want to copy move or copy and the core Cursor icons don't have that but drag and drop does.

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out it works DragSource.DefaultMoveDrop and DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop actually work in a normal swing application, just not on JPanel inside a SwingNode which the environment I am working in uses. (I can't change this)

Therefore if you run into this issue and you are NOT mixing the frameworks this forms an answer.